# Stuttering Translate3D when using rellax.js on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, css, html, plugins, parallax

I am currently working on my portfolio site, and I wanted to have some kind of parallax effect. So after I researched I bit, I found rellax.js, which claims to work on mobile browsers too. But now when I view [my site](https://fresh.designz.at) on a mobile browser, it is stuttering. I was wondering if this is an Issue from my site, or if it is a general problem with this plugin(even though the example site of rellax.js works perfectly fine on mobile Browsers).

Where to look (and how to recreate) for the stuttering effect: The plugin affects the Header part of the site as well as the card that is somewhat overlapping the header on scrolling. To achieve the effect just scroll the site down and up.

I hope I provided enough information about my problem. The problem **can't** be recreated on a site like jsfiddle or codepen, because I don't know what is causing it.